# E-mail rendered XML

Tags: java, xml, grails, groovy

I have the following 'render as xml' code in my controller, it is working as expected, however I am looking to email this page or the contents of this page in it's XML format.  I'm confused as how to go about doing this. Thanks in advance.

```
def xmlList = {
  def list = foo.list()
  render(contentType:"text/xml"){
    foo{
      bar{
        for(a in list){ 
          foobar(id:a..id)  
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you already know how to send an email from a Grails application (if you don't post a separate question about that). If this assumption is valid, then all you need to figure out how to store the generated XML in a variable, rather than returning it to the browser. The answer is simply to use the `XMLBuilder` API directly, rather than passing the XML-generating closure to the `render` method:

```
def xmlList = {
  def list = foo.list()

  def builder = new XMLBuilder()
  def result = builder.build {
    foo {
      bar {
        for(a in list) { 
          foobar(id:a..id)  
        }
      }
    }
  }

  def emailBody = result.toString()

  // Now pass the emailBody (along with the recipient address, subject line, etc.)
  // to whatever you use to send emails
}
```